# Converting int to int* in python

Tags: python, c++

We are using SWIG to test C++ API with Python.  One of the method in C++ expects `int *` as
`int fnClicTestIntPtr(int *)`; It just adds one at returns value. I am trying to call this method in Python and test the output. Can you please tell me how can i pass `int*` in Pyhton.

My interface file looks like this:

```
   %module ClicTest
   %{
   #include "ClicTest.h"

   %}
   %include <windows.i>
   %include "ClicTest.h"
```

Header file:

```
  #ifdef CLICTEST_EXPORTS
  #define CLICTEST_API __declspec(dllexport)
  #else
  #define CLICTEST_API __declspec(dllimport)
  #endif

 // This class is exported from the ClicTest.dll
 class CLICTEST_API CClicTest {
 public:
CClicTest(void);
// TODO: add your methods here.
  };

 extern CLICTEST_API int nClicTest;

 CLICTEST_API int fnClicTest(void);

 CLICTEST_API int fnClicTestInt(int);

 CLICTEST_API char* fnClicTestChar(char *);

 CLICTEST_API int fnClicTestIntPtr(int *);

 CLICTEST_API int fnClicTestVoidPtr(void *);

 CLICTEST_API char* fnClicTestCharPtr(char *);

 CLICTEST_API long fnClicTestLongPtr(long *);
```

I tried passing a number , also tried using ctypes.byref and ctypes.pointer methods. But nothing has been successfull.Like below

Py file:

```
 print(ClicTest.fnClicTestLongPtr(ctypes.pointer(num)))
 print(ClicTest.fnClicTestLongPtr(num))
 print(ClicTest.fnClicTestLongPtr(ctypes.byref(num)))
```

-

```
Error : TypeError: in method 'fnClicTestIntPtr', argument 1 of type 'int *
```

Comment: Could you abstract your problem into self-contained example and explain what exactly your problem is? The snippet of your code is not enough to reproduce, or even figure out what are you asking for. And I got totally lost with why are you trying to cast anything to `void *`...

Comment: We had to include “cpointer.i” interface in the interface file (connecting C++ to Python using SWIG). Refer to http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/Library.html#Library for more details

Answer (score 0):

We had to include “cpointer.i” interface in the interface file (connecting C++ to Python using SWIG). Refer to http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/Library.html#Library for more details